# How to center Grid inside Contentpanel GWT

Tags: gwt, grid, gxt

I need anyone to tell me how to center Grid inside the contentpanel.

I created content panel width 100% and the grid width is 50% and I need to center the grid inside the contentpanel.

thank you in advance,

Answer (score 1):

You can use CenterLayoutContainer widget.
Sample code:

```
@Override
public Widget asWidget() {
    //Your panel
    ContentPanel panel = new ContentPanel(); 
    //Сontainer with your content
    CenterLayoutContainer container = new CenterLayoutContainer();
    container.add(yourGrid);
    //Put container into panel
    panel.setWidget(container);
    return panel;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `CenterLayoutContainer`: http://www.sencha.com/examples/#ExamplePlace:centerlayout

This is for the new version, 3.0. The older 2.2.5 also has an analogous layout type.

Comment: Could be worth pointing out that a center layout wont assign a size, so you need to size the grid ahead of time or it won't be drawn cleanly.